# Centering a <div>

Tags: html, css, center, fixed

Good evening,

I am trying to center a 'Contact Details' div. I used the below code however after using *position: fixed* it doesn't look like it's centered. Is there another way to have it centered perfectly while using *position:fixed*? I would like to keep the div centered while one scrolls up and down. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

```css
.secondary {
 height: 350px;
 width: 400px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
 margin-top: 200px;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 40%;
}
```

```html
<section class="secondary">
 <h3>Contact Details</h3>
   <ul class="contact-info">
     <li class="phone"><a href="tel:###-###-####">###-###-####</a></li>
  <li class="mail"><a href="mailto:e************@gmail.com"             target="_blank">e************@gmail.com</a></li>
  <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?screen_name=ec#######" target="_blank">@ec*******</a></li>
  <li class="linkedin"><a href="http://linkedin.com/in/e####-######-8a791988" target="_blank">Edwin Castro</a></li>
 </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using fixed dimensions for your div rather than making it responsive you could use:

```
.secondary {
    height: 350px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: -200px;
    margin-top: -175px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

All it does is move the element to the center then use a negative margin to pull it back by half its total width/height leaving it perfectly centered.

This feels like quite an outdated approach though. If you did wish to make this responsive instead you could try something like:

```
.secondary {
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

It may not give you the precise styling you're looking for but it'll put you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, that worked exactly how I wanted it. The styling remained the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Replace `.secondary` with this :)

```
.secondary {
    background-color: #ccc;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 40px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```